# While converting a pandas dataframe to h2oframe in python getting "job is missing" error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, h2o

I have build a model in H2o and while testing the same getting the below error. So while testing I am converting the input pandas dataframe to h2o frame so that it can feed into the model for prediction. Below is the sample code for the same. Please help me in getting this issue resolved.

Code Snippet:

```
na_list = ['NA', 'none', 'nan', 'etc']  
df = pd.DataFrame(np_data['tempdict'], index=[0])  
**hf = h2o.H2OFrame(df,na_strings=na_list)**    #this is the line where it is failing.  
prediction = model.predict(hf)[:, 1]
```

Error while converting to h2oframe
[image]

Comment: Can you please also include how `np_data` is defined? Please share the whole script so that it can be reproduced? Also, please share the version of H2O you are using for reproducibility purposes.